# 50% background-image + 50% background-color in one?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

Is it possible with CSS to apply a background-color and a background-image in one div at the same time?
I want it like this. Half image, half color. Ignore the blur effect, I don't need that:
[image: I want it like this. Half image, half color. Ignore the blur effect, I don't need that.]

The reason why I want this is because I have to apply an adjustment-layer on it all the time to get this effect.

Comment: It's possible to apply a background-image and a background-color at the same time ... but will not result as you expect, for that you will need to manage an overlay with rgba values or opacity. Please share what you have tried

Comment: So I should place a transparent layer over it?

Comment: if you put a semi-transparent image (png/gif) over a colored background, the color should show through, but it will only be configurable by editing the image file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Background color will only apply to the transparent parts of the background image (*if both are set on an element*).

You could create a pseudo element though with `:before` or `:after` and use that for the color layer.

(*if you want to put content inside the element, you should use the pseudo element for the background image*)

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(200, 50, 50, 0.5);
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  color:#fff;
}
.background:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/400/cats/1') 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
content here..
</div>
```